# How to get discount from Quote in Magento 2 Checkout

Tags: e-commerce, magento2, checkout, quote

I have this url who has many Quote methods from Magento 2. Note that Quote is a class who has a data from checkout page in magento 2.

Url: https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/class_magento_1_1_quote_1_1_model_1_1_quote.html

But i dont see a method like CheckoutConfig in javascript who has base_discount_amount like image:

[image]

How to get Base Discount Amount programatically in PHP backend from checkout page Magento 2?????

I should not use javascript because it will be a security fail